# GetElementBy What? Address a webpage button in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to suss out how I need to address this button on a webpage via VBA.

```
<button type="button" onclick="moveOptions(this.form['things'],this.form['selected_things']);">Move Down</button>
```

There's no ID, Tagname, etc which I would normally use. Alternatively if there was another way to trigger the onclick event independently that would work as well. It's one of those dual tables where values are in one table and you select and click to move to the other. I've already gotten the selection portion down.

Comment: _"There's no ID, **Tagname**, etc..."_ But there is. The tagname is `button`.

Comment: You can use `IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")(<index_ID>)`